# batch_distance.cpp:274: error: (-215:Assertion failed)

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, sift

` I have the following code :

```
import cv2 
import os
from os import listdir
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tabulate import tabulate
import itertools


#sift
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

#feature matching
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=True)

# get the path/directory
folder_dir = "./runs/myDetect/SIFT"

col_names = []
data = []
all_keypoints = []
all_descriptors = []

for image in os.listdir(folder_dir):

    
    # check if the image ends with png or jpg or jpeg
    if (image.endswith(".png") or image.endswith(".jpg") or image.endswith(".jpeg")):
        
        col_names = ["KeyPoints lenght", "Numbers", "Keypoints"]

        opened_img = np.array(Image.open(folder_dir + image))
        
        gray_img= cv2.cvtColor(opened_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        keypoints, descriptors = sift.detectAndCompute(gray_img, None)
        data.append([image, len(keypoints)])
        all_keypoints.append([image, keypoints])
        all_descriptors.append([descriptors]) #all_descriptors.append([image, descriptors])

print(tabulate(data, headers=col_names, tablefmt="fancy_grid"))

         
for a, b in itertools.combinations(all_descriptors, 2):

    a=np.array(a).astype('uint8')
    print(type(a))
    b=np.array(b).astype('uint8')
    print(type(b))
    if type(a)!=type(None) and type(b)!=type(None) :

        if a or b is None:
          print(False)

        matches = bf.match(a,b)
        matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am trying to find similarities between 2 images on the same file. I am using SIFT. Output of SIFT are keypoints and descriptor. I created a list named all_descriptors and for each image I add new descriptor to this list. Finally, I want to compare this descriptors between each other. On this part `matches = bf.match(a,b)` of the code, I receive following error : `matches = bf.match(a,b)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/batch_distance.cpp:274: error: (-215:Assertion failed) type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U) in function 'batchDistance'. What is the solution? How can I compare 2 images in the same file?

Comment: You're using OpenCV. It contains function `imread`. Why are you using PIL to load the image? Not only are you bloating your code with redundant libraries, you also making unnecessary mistakes. Since PIL uses RGB order by default, your colour coversion `COLOR_BGR2GRAY` is incorrect -- the weights used for red, green and blue are different in the formula, so when you swap the channels, the result changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the same code with steps in below

1. First :

```
all_descriptors.append(descriptors)
```

2. then :

```
a=np.array(a).astype('float32')
```

Comment: Why should someone "try" this? What were the problems, where is that documented, and how does this address them?